# C# dataset sql questions

Tags: c#

What I have going on is a list of ID's (nc.txt) and a list of columns (listbox1).

I am trying to export from SQL all data from the list of ID's that match the list of columns.  I'm sure i dont have the dataset right.  Any help aprpicated.

update:
string contents = File.ReadAllText(textBox3.Text);

```
            string id = id = Regex.Match(contents, @"CoreDBCaseID=(?<id>\d+)").Groups["id"].Value;
            string server = server = Regex.Match(contents, @"Server=(?<Server>[^;]+)").Groups["Server"].Value;
            string security = security = Regex.Match(contents, "Security=(?<Security>[^;]+)").Groups["Security"].Value;
            string database = database = Regex.Match(contents, "Database=(?<Database>[^\r]+)").Groups["Database"].Value;

            string[] data = new string[] {
                    string.Format("Table={0}", id),
                    string.Format("Server={0}", server),
                    string.Format("Security={0}", security),
                    string.Format("Database={0}", database),
                };
                    string sqltable = ("dbo.SLTDS_C" + id + "_Stdtable");
                    string ids = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\nc.txt").Aggregate((f, s) => f + "," + s);
                    String cols = String.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray());
                    string sql = "select " + cols + " from sqltable where ([id] in (" + ids + "))";
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=" + security);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter tabadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet("dataset");
                tabadapter.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Source,cols);
                DataTable tbltarget;
                tbltarget = dataset.Tables[cols];
                string headers = dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Aggregate((f, s) => f.Name + "," + s.Name);
                string sqldata = dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Aggregate((f, s) => f.Value + "," + s.Value);
                string output_text = tbltarget.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(col => col.ColumnName).Aggregate((current, next) => current + "|" + next) + "\r\n"
                + tbltarget.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row.ItemArray.Aggregate((current, next) => current.ToString() + "|" + next.ToString())).Cast<string>().Aggregate((current, next) => current + "\r\n" + next);
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\outputtest.txt", output_text);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error 1 'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 2 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have a typo. Your `DataSet` is named `datase`, not `database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well fix this:

```
result_table.FillSchema(database, SchemaType.Source,cols);
```

Looks like you intended this, variable datase instead of database:

```
result_table.FillSchema(datase, SchemaType.Source,cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable.Columns` and `DataTable.Rows` are not generic collections.  They're of type `DataColumnCollection` and `DataRowCollection`, respectively.  These are collection types that predate .NET 2.0; before generics in .NET 2.0, you had to create a specific class for any strongly-typed collection.

To get something compatible with LINQ methods, do one of these:

`dataset.Tables[0].Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()`

`dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()`

The difference is that `OfType` will get only those items that can be cast to that type, and discard the rest, whereas `Cast` will expect the collection to contain *only* items that can be cast to that type, and will throw an exception if it encounters one that can't be.

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to give a lot more explanation than that.  "Neither worked" because of *what*!?  You got an error?  Your code wouldn't compile?  Your power went out?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataColumn>' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `OfType` and `Cast` "work", but that doesn't necessarily mean that everything you put after them works.  Remember that you're getting an `IEnumerable<DataColumn>` or `IEnumerable<DataRow>` out of them.  You need to use operations that work on DataColumns or DataRows.  It looks to me like you're using Aggregate incorrectly.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am I need an export of the database as following:

Column1|column2|column3|column4
X,4,3,1


Columns1()=whichever columns selected in the listbox
x 4,3,1 is the listing the row that matches whatevers in the column

Comment: columns1|columns2|column3|column4  
x,4,3,1

Comment: well it's actually a new line and a hard return between column4 and x.  Comments wont let me seperate.

Comment: You can get your column names, separated by vertical bars, by doing something like this:  `string.Join("|", table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray());`

Comment: You can get each column's data in a similar way like this: `table.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(row => Debug.Print(string.Join("|", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())));`